# How to check if a value is in an array without the use of a For loop?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop

Is this possible and/or recommended?  Currently, the issue I'm having is that the processing time of this code I have checks for a value in an array of ~40 for a value, once it finds it we set a boolean.  This same for loop is called up to 20 times so I was wondering if there was a way I could optimize this code in a better way to where I don't need to have several for loops checking for a single answer.

Here's an example of the code

```
For i = 0 to iCount 'iCount up to 40
 If name = UCase((m_Array(i, 1))) Then
  <logic>
 End If
Next
```

Above is an example of what I"m looking at, this little chunk of code checks the array which is prepopulated prior to running this function and is usually around 30-40 items in the array.  With this being called up to 20 times I feel I could reduce the amount of time it takes to run this if I could find another way to do it without the use of so many for loops.

Comment: Rather than an array, a List(of String) would allow you to test with `if myList.Contains(name)` so would an `ArrayList`

Comment: Just stash the array contents into a Dictionary.

Comment: Hashtables were built for speed.

Comment: `HashSet(of Type)` is the official single list of keys type to use for speedy lookups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ provides a `Contains` extension method, which returns a `Boolean`, but that won't work for multidimensional arrays.  Even if it did work, if performance is the concern, then `Contains` wouldn't help much since, internally, all the `Contains` method does is loop through the items until it finds the matching item.

One way to make it faster, is to use an `Exit For` statement to exit the loop once the first matching item is found.  At least then it won't continue searching through the rest of the items after it finds the one for which it was looking:

```
For i = 0 to iCount 'iCount up to 40
    If name = UCase((m_Array(i, 1))) Then
        ' logic...
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If you don't want it to have to search through the array at all, you would need to index your data.  The simplest way to index your data is with a hash table.  The `Dictionary` class is an easy to use implementation of a hash table.  However, in the end, a hash table (just like any other indexing method) will only help performance if the situation is right.  In this situation, where the array only contains 40 or so items, it's quite possible that a hash table will be slower.  The only way to know for sure is to test it both ways and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: You forgot to mention HashSets and [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Neolisk Good point.  Although, `Array.IndexOf` only works with one dimension arrays too.  `HashSet` would be useful, *IF* the items really are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently searching the list repeatedly and doing something if a member has certain properties. Instead you could check the properties of an item once, when you add an item to the list, and perform the logic then. Instead of repeating the tests it's then only done once. No searching at all is better than even the fastest search.